# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'absl'

Tags: tensorflow

I followed instructions (https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) to install the Tensorflow Object Detection API. I use Anaconda on ubuntu18.4 and all of the steps in the instructions seemed to complete OK.

When I train to train my model with the following command:

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 31, in <module>
    from absl import flags
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'absl'
```

I get the error mentioned in the headline. I would be very thankful if someone could help me with a code example to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `absl` package; to install it, use either one of the following:

```
pip install absl-py
```

or if you are in a Conda environment:

```
conda install -c anaconda absl-py
```